# meaning of <SomeClass extends ?> in java?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

During an interview with one of the big software companies, the interviewer asked whether I know java, and I said yes. 
Then he said tell me what's the meaning of these two:

```
<? extends SomeClass> 
<SomeClass extends ?>
```

The first one I explained, but the 2nd form I couldn't figure out. I said I am not sure if that's a valid syntax and if it has any meaning. 
What's the meaning of `<SomeClass extends ?>`, or was the interviewer just testing me with a wrong syntax to see whether I can identify?

Comment: `<SomeClass extends ?>` well my IDE says "Unexpected Token", so they were just messing with you.

Comment: There is no `<SomeClass extends ?>` syntax in Java (and yes, you probably should know it - depending on position you ware trying to get).

Comment: If that was how the question was presented, what a terrible interview question.

Comment: Sounds like a useless interview question.

Comment: Doubt it useless; I'm sure it showed whoever exactly what they're looking for. From a logical standpoint it doesn't even make sense; it's not actually bounding anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Interviewer was just testing you with wrong syntax. At least you be able to recognize this right away next time. Learn from experience :)

Comment: What confused me is that in the pre interview email it was clearly saying we won't trick you during the interview or ask wrong questions...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which company was this? You could contact your recruiter but they prob can't do much. Just learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

< ? extends SomeClass> This is what generics are all about, while declaration if you opt for not declaring the type of class then you can provide ? Instead this means that it can be any class which extends SomeClass.

< SomeClass extends ?> This is just to test your skills, this one is not a valid syntax because you cannot make a probability of extension of a class at the time of definition and at run time just supply the class. This is against the rules of Inheritance in Java.